# Can't access files in Apache Spark, brand new to Spark, using for an Independent Study in college

Tags: apache-spark

I'm a newbie using Apache Spark for an independent study this semester and I can't figure out how to access files to run Spark on. I'm using Spark: The Definitive Guide: Big Data Processing Made Simple  ISBN-10: 1491912219 and the command that I'm stuck at is "head data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv", it gives me the error ":24: error: not found: value". Running down what I've done thus far.

1. downloaded Apache Spark 2.4.4 Prebuilt for Apache Hadoop 2.7
2. at this point, I can use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (WSL) to cd into the spark directory and run ".bin/spark-shell" to start spark
3. I'm able to run the first few commands the book provides "val myRange = spark.range(1000).toDF("number")", "val divisBy2 = myRange.where("number % 2 = 0")" and "divisBy2.count()".
4. downloaded the spark-the-definitive-guide-master files from github and placed them in the relevant directories. (this is where the .CSV file I reference, lives)

My assumption is that I'm not providing Spark with the proper path to the file that I want it to operate on. I don't know how to do that though.

1. I tried following this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYNsaR-gOsA which details the creation of a winutils and spark folder on C:, which I did, and then editing environment variables "hadoop_home" and "spark_home" and path "%spark_home%\bin". That didn't seem to do anything.
2. While messing around with both of the previous things I've mentioned I've tried various commands in Spark such as "ls", "cd", "head /mnt/c/spark/data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv", and "head /mnt/c/users/ian/desktop/spark_and_big_data/spark/data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv". None of which have worked.

I'm clearly missing something big here, like having to use some other command to direct Spark as to what home directory it should be parked in.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the output of "head /mnt/c/spark/data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv"?

Comment: The same as any head operation, "error ":24: error: not found: value". I've tried all sorts of /mnt/ and even moved the file folders around via gui in Windows to see if for some reason the file location nwas the problem.

Comment: exact output - https://ibb.co/ZTg404X

Comment: You are in the Scala shell which is the wrong place to type those commands(cd, head etc.) in. It should be the default shell (e.g. bash) of your linux subsystem on windows.

Comment: ?So I start Ubuntu, cd into the folder that has my spark files, start up spark with spark-shell, once I start spark shell I can't navigate anywhere?

Comment: So I started Ubuntu, cd to the folder which has 2015-summary.csv. I started spark-shell, and tried to run an operation on 2015-summary.csv, which my terminal is currently in the same folder with, but Spark does not see the file. Am I still fundamentally not understanding how this works?

Comment: %ENVVAR% and “\” are of the Windows path format. $ and / are for Linux. Did you export the environment variables?

Comment: I eventually managed to get everything functioning properly with the help of a professor. I'm still fuzzy on exactly what we were doing wrong, because my other professor couldn't get it working either. Now everything is functioning. As LShi said, "head" is not going to work in the Scala shell. Secondarily, my professor and I were using an incorrect format when trying to access files with other commands. I don't recall exactly what it was but the correct format is "spark.read.csv("/mnt/c/spark/data/flight-data/csv/localdisktest.csv").show"

Comment: Books are sometimes outdated, so the official documentation should be the canonical place to learn the API/usage.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to get everything functioning properly with the help of a professor. I'm still fuzzy on exactly what we were doing wrong, because my other professor couldn't get it working either. Now everything is functioning. As LShi said, "head" is not going to work in the Scala shell. Secondarily, my professor and I were using an incorrect format when trying to access files with other commands. I don't recall exactly what it was but the correct format is "spark.read.csv("/mnt/c/spark/data/flight-data/csv/localdisktest.csv").show"